# How do I exclude a certain line when using shuf in bash script?

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to shuffle the content inside a text file while keeping the content on the first line the same. I have tried the following to shuffle a.txt into b.txt but I'm not quite sure how to keep line one's content untouched when moving it to b.txt

```
shuf a.txt -o b.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

> while keeping the content on the first line the same.

So extract the first line and deal with the rest separately. A script might look like:

```
{
    IFS= read -r firstline
    printf "%s\n" "$firstline"
    shuf
} < a.txt > b.txt
```

but for a beginner in shell using `head -n1` and `tail -n +2` might be more understandable.

Comment: So if I were to use head -n1 and tail -n + 2, would I do head -n1 | tail -n +2| shuff a.txt -o b.txt?

Comment: `head -n1 a.txt > b.txt` `tail -n +2 a.txt | shuf >> b.txt`